# how to get rgb values for a color that's close to another color?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, colors, rgb

If I have a color in RGB. How can I create a javascript function that returns true when another RGB value is close to the initial RGB and false otherwise?

Comment: Does this have to do with Canvas/user input? And are you using jQuery?

Comment: Could you give an example of a color which would be close to another and one which would not be close to it?

Comment: It all depends on how you define 'close'.  Do you mean close in hue?  Close in luminosity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used this and it works very well for me:

```
// assuming that color1 and color2 are objects with r, g and b properties
// and tolerance is the "distance" of colors in range 0-255
function isNeighborColor(color1, color2, tolerance) {
    if(tolerance == undefined) {
        tolerance = 32;
    }

    return Math.abs(color1.r - color2.r) <= tolerance
        && Math.abs(color1.g - color2.g) <= tolerance
        && Math.abs(color1.b - color2.b) <= tolerance;
}
```

and depending on your particular problem the meaning of the color distance can be different, for example maybe in your case you would need to change `&&` to `||`

Answer (score 1):

It all depends what means 'close' to you. You can make function like:

```
var color1 = { "r": 255, "g": 255, "b": 255 }
var color2 = { "r": 250, "g": 252, "b": 252 }

function isClose(color1, color2) {
    var threshold = 30;
    var distance = Math.abs(color1.r - color2.r) + Math.abs(color1.g - color2.g) + Math.abs(color1.b - color2.b);

    if (distance < threshold) return true;
    return false;
}
```

which would match colors that are *very* close (based on simple rgb vector distance), but still there is a *threshold* parameter which has to be chosen experimentally.

Comment: wouldnt threshold be higher than 255 then? In Photoshop for example the maximum tolerance is 255, yours would be 765