# If the color on the screen equals a certain color, Java

Tags: java, colors, timer, screen, updating

Part of my program needs to see if the color at a certain point on the screen equals a certain color then preform an action. I can not figure out how to constantly check the point on the screen to see if that color changes. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
static Color coal1 = new Color(19, 19, 18); //color i want to match up    

int xRock = gameSquare.x + x_scale; // points on the screen
int yRock = gameSquare.y + y_scale;

java.awt.Color c = robot.getPixelColor(xRock, yRock);//finds the rgb color of the point

if (!c.equals(coal1)){ //this is the part where I am stuck!

}
```

I want it to keep looping until c no longer equals coal1. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: New problem is that I can not send through the c to check if it is = to coal1.

New Code (Main Body)

```
package Restart;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBuffer;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.util.Timer;

public class MineCoal {

    public static Rectangle gameSquare;
    public static boolean runningMine = true;
    static Timer timer = new Timer("Printer");
    static MyTask t = new MyTask();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        lookCoal();

    }

    public static void lookCoal() throws InterruptedException{

        Thread.sleep(2000);
        try {
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            while(runningMine == true){

                gameSquare = new Rectangle(287,139,551,356); //== game square
                BufferedImage img = robot.createScreenCapture(gameSquare);
                WritableRaster r = img.getRaster();
                DataBuffer db = r.getDataBuffer();
                DataBufferInt dbi = (DataBufferInt)db;
                int[] data = dbi.getData();                 

                for (int x_scale = 0; x_scale < gameSquare.width; x_scale += 1) {
                    for(int y_scale = 0; y_scale < gameSquare.height; y_scale += 1) {
                        int rgb = data[x_scale + gameSquare.width * y_scale];

                        if ( (rgb == -15658737)||(rgb ==-15527150) ){ //finds coal
                            //checkinv();
                            if (runningMine == true){

                                runningMine = false;

                                int xRock = gameSquare.x + x_scale; // sets the x and y of the point
                                int yRock = gameSquare.y + y_scale;
                                robot.mouseMove(xRock, yRock);
                                java.awt.Color c = robot.getPixelColor(xRock, yRock); // gets the color of the point
                                System.out.println(c);

                                Thread.sleep(500);
                                robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                                robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
                                Thread.sleep(1000);
                                System.out.println("Found Rock");

                                timer.schedule(t, 0, 2000); //this goes to check if the point has changed colors but I can not send c through

                            }

                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Timer Class

```
package Restart;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.util.TimerTask;

class MyTask extends TimerTask {
    //times member represent calling times.
    private int times = 0;
    static Color coal1 = new Color(19, 19, 18);


    public void run() {

        if (coal1.equals(c)) {  //I can not get the c from the other class to compair with coal1
            System.out.println("color is the same");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("color changed");

            //Stop Timer.
            this.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.Timer`'s **[`schedule(TimerTask, long, long)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)** method is probably up to the job.

Regarding your updated post:
You'll have to move

```
java.awt.Color c = robot.getPixelColor(xRock, yRock); // gets the color of the point
```

inside the `run()` method of your TimerTask. And since it needs variables `robot`, `xRock` and `yRock`, you'll have to pass them as arguments to a custom constructor.
E.g.:

```
/* In 'lookCoal(); method */
  // timer.schedule(t, 0 2000)   // <-- replace that with this:
  timer.schedule(new MyTask(robot, xRock, yRock), 0, 2000);

/* In 'MyTask' Class */
  // Add the required variables:
  Robot robot;
  int xRock, yRock;

  // Add a constructor like this:
  MyTask(Robot r, int x, int y) {
      this.robot = r;
      this.xRock = x;
      this.yRock = y;
  }

  // Modify the run method, like this:
  public void run() {
      java.awt.Color c = this.robot.getPixelColor(this.xRock, this.yRock);
      ...
```

Comment: Okay but now I can not send the variable c to the class with the run method for c to compare with coal1.

Comment: Update your answer with what you have tried sofar and where you are stuck, so we can help further.

Comment: Of course it does. Good thing you don't need that, so you can remove the line altogether :P I ain't going to code that game for you. I give you the main direction, but you have to work out the details :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help so far and that's what I wanted is the main direction. This was just putting me for a loop for some reason.

Comment: Always glad to help :) If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to spot it easily.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use javascript. This post can help in how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/a/11506531/1083581

Once you are able to get the required rgb values, you can use an ajax request or a javascript submit, for further processing on the server. 

HTH